it is possible to set the depth of number_sections in rmarkdown?
My YAML setting is like:
---
title: "XXX"
subtitle: 'XXX'
author: 'by XXX'
output: 
    pdf_document:
        toc: true
        toc_depth: 3
        number_sections: true
---

Is it possible to limit the depth of the number_sections in 3?
I expected to see the contents
# header 1

aaa

## header 2

bbb

### header 3

ccc

### header 3 (2)

cccc

#### header 4

dddd

being rendered like this:

1 header 1
aaa
1.1 header 2
bbb
1.1.1 header 3
ccc
1.1.2 header 3 (2)
cccc
header 4
dddd

